# Recent update to 16.04 causes Unity to crash whenever the Search tool is used

Tags: 16.04, unity, crash, search

Not sure what happened but hoping someone can help.  Running Trusty Tahr on a Thinkpad T410.  Ever since Thursday morning (October 26) when I applied the latest updates, Unity crashes every time I click the "Search your computer" icon at the top of the launcher.  Pressing the "Super" key causes the same crash.  The "Shutdown" and "Restart" buttons don't do anything (I have to open the terminal and enter "sudo shutdown" to shut down the computer).  HELP!  More than happy to provide ANY documentation you require.  My desktop computer (an HP Pavilion) is at the exact same maintenance level and is not experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got proper assistance on the "Questions: Ubuntu" at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Problem was caused by using the mesa drivers from the X-Swat PPA.  Reverted back to mainline and the problem has been solved.